# How to fix Nodemon exit on changes issue

Tags: linux, node.js, ubuntu, forever, nodemon

everyone. I like to use nodemon while developing with node.js because its restart on changes feature. I never had any problem at all. But since I updated Ubuntu from 13.04 to 13.10 it fails to restart on every change I make, so I have to restart my server manually. I run my apps as always, like so:

```
nodemon app.js
```

and with some config options like:

```
nodemon app.js production
```

The problem is, like I said, that even if the file I'm modifying is a client side one, I happen to get:

```
9 Nov 13:48:29 - [nodemon] v0.7.10
9 Nov 13:48:29 - [nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
9 Nov 13:48:29 - [nodemon] watching: /home/alevardi/render/wip/paraiso
9 Nov 13:48:29 - [nodemon] starting `node app.js`
Express server listening on port 3000
Successfully connected to MongoDB
9 Nov 13:48:51 - [nodemon] exiting
```

The last line of the output above, appears when I change a file. So, what can i do for fixing this awful issue? It is driving me crazy! 
NOTE: I've tried with Forever and supervisor with the same results. 
Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Try node-dev instead. Same thing as nodemon basically but maybe it doesn't have this issue.

Comment: I tried. It doesn't work neither. :(

Comment: Hmm. Weird. Sounds like perhaps something is broken with the setup on your machine but that type of issue is difficult to resolve via stackoverflow. Maybe try to get interactive help with IRC.

Comment: Can you file an issue at http://github.com/remy/nodemon/issues - is it can be replicated, then it can be fixed.